# Telerik UI in Angular 2 - Sortable Grid only loads data after manual sort

Tags: angular, api, user-interface, kendo-ui, telerik

I've been working with a Telerik sortable Grid in an ASP.Net Core 2 Angular 2 SPA, the data I'm working with is the fetchdata.component that comes with the project. I've been able to load data into the grid but the data only seems to populate after a filter field is activated by mouse click. On initial load the grid will show up empty with 'No records available' under the first column leaving all other non-header data empty. Attached below is my attempt so far to code the typescript and html files for the Telerik sorting grid. Let me know what part of this effects the on-load behavior and what might be entered, phrased, or positioned incorrectly here. Any helpful suggestions would be appreciated!

fetchdata.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { weatherData } from './fetch'
import { SortDescriptor, orderBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { GridDataResult } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

@Component({
    selector: 'fetchdata',
    templateUrl: './fetchdata.component.html'
})
export class FetchDataComponent {
    public forecasts: Array<WeatherForecast>;
    public multiple: boolean = false;
    public allowUnsort: boolean = true;
    public teststring: string;

    private sort: SortDescriptor[] = [];
    private gridView: GridDataResult;

    constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {

        http.get(baseUrl + '/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts').subscribe(result => {
            this.forecasts = result.json() as WeatherForecast[];
        });
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        alert(this.forecasts.length)
        this.loadForecasts();
    }

    protected sortChange(sort: SortDescriptor[]): void {
        this.sort = sort;      
        this.loadForecasts();
    }

    protected loadForecasts(): void {
        this.gridView = {
            data: orderBy(this.forecasts, this.sort),
            total: this.forecasts.length
        };
    }
}

interface WeatherForecast {
    id: number;
    dateFormatted: string;
    temperatureC: number;
    temperatureF: number;
    summary: string;
}
```

fetchdata.component.html:

```
<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

<div class="example-config">
    <label class="k-form-field">
        <input class="k-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="allowUnsort"
               [(ngModel)]="allowUnsort" />
        <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="allowUnsort">
            {{ allowUnsort ? 'Disable': 'Enable' }} unsorting
        </label>
    </label><br />
    <label class="k-form-field">
        <input class="k-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="multiple"
               [(ngModel)]="multiple" />
        <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="multiple">
            {{ multiple ? 'Disable': 'Enable' }} multiple columns sorting
        </label>
    </label>
</div>
<kendo-grid [data]="gridView"
            [height]="530"
            [sortable]="{
            allowUnsort: allowUnsort,
            mode: multiple ? 'multiple' : 'single'
            }"
            [sort]="sort"
            (sortChange)="sortChange($event)">
    <kendo-grid-column field="dateFormatted" title="Date" width="200" filter="date" format="{0:d}"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="temperatureC" title="Temp. (C)" width="150" filter="numeric"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="temperatureF" title="Temp. (F)" width="150" filter="numeric"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="summary" title="Summary" width="200"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

Comment: Good news - after consulting with Telerik directly it looks like an instance of this.loadForecasts(); needs to be in the body of the API call. Hopefully that helps for anyone who's stuck beating their head on a wall with this!  I'll post an example below.

Comment: constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        http.get(baseUrl + '/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts').subscribe(result => {
            this.forecasts = result.json() as WeatherForecast[];
            this.loadForecasts();
        });
    }